# How can I prevent the dark theme from breaking the CSS in my HTML emails?

Tags: html, css, email

When creating an HTML email, it is possible that some clients, such as Gmail, will break the CSS that you have set. For example, you might set a div element to have a background-color of COLOR and a p tag to have a color of white, but these styles may not be properly applied in certain email clients.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="gmail-blend-screen">
        <div class="gmail-blend-difference">
            <p>Your text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.container {
    background-image: linear-gradient(COLOR, COLOR);
}

p {
    color:white;
}

u+.body .gmail-blend-screen {
    background: #000;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

u+.body .gmail-blend-difference {
    background: #000;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

> More details on: https://www.hteumeuleu.com/2021/fixing-gmail-dark-mode-css-blend-modes/